# How to store value of json object in angular2 variable.

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have the following  code :
    this.http.post('xx.php',data)
    .subscribe(
    (response)=>{}

The response I get back is in format : {"P_0":"7554","N_0":"Renu Sensitive Lens Solution 355 ml"}

How do I store values 7554/Renue...355ml in a angular2 variable? I am only able to console.log 7554 if I write response.json().P_0 but I dont want to do that. There can be other variable names like P_1,P_2,P_3 coming along with this data. 
I have just strated angular 2 days back. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
let res=response.json();
let keys = Object.keys(res);
let result=[];
for(let i=0,l=keys.length;i<l;i++){
   result[]=res[keys[i]];
}
console.log(result.join('/'));
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped

Comment: If you are satisfied then put a tick as correct answer for others to help.